# How to make a good practice naming your controllers in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

So i have an application in rails and i make a controller named views for all my static views that don't involve the database, so is a good practice make 
`def contact` and `def index` for the landing page in my views controller
or i should make a contact controller and use index method?

I know it works but its really a good practice?

Comment: give the rails guide a read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

Comment: A good practice is to adhere to the single responsibility principle so that each controller does one job - in other words each controller should manage only one resource. Most things like a contact page con be done with the standard CRUD verbs. Calling your controller `ViewsController` makes me want to facepalm - hard. If you want to have a controller for static pages just call it Pages or StaticController.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to do it as scaffold does, for example to generate a controller for Home page where I put def Index and another controller named Contact which would have def Index, def New, def Update, etc...

But, if you are thinking on a landing page it could be in one single controller, like all in Home Controller.